# CSS in Blazor Component Library doesnt load

Tags: blazor-server-side

In my razor components project, I am adding a blazor component library to the solution. I can call the components in the component library from my .app project, but it seems that .css and other files don't load from the Blazor component library.
I looked into the component library .csproj file, but I can't figure out what is missing:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
        <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- .js/.css files will be referenced via <script>/<link> tags; other content files will just be included in the app's 'dist' directory without any tags referencing them -->
        <EmbeddedResource Include="content\**\*.js" LogicalName="blazor:js:%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="content\**\*.css" LogicalName="blazor:css:%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="content\**" Exclude="**\*.js;**\*.css" LogicalName="blazor:file:%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />    
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Browser" Version="3.0.0-preview-19075-0444" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Build" Version="3.0.0-preview-19075-0444" PrivateAssets="all" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Don't forget `webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets();` on `public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>`   [Consume content from a referenced RCL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#consume-content-from-a-referenced-rcl)

Answer (score 2):

This a limitation with the current release of Razor Components. It can't import static assets from components libraries. As workaround, you should copy them manually until is fixed in next releases.

Comment: Is this still an issue yet? There is an issue on Github for that topic: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13854.

Answer (score 0):

Static assets should work now since preview 6. Please read blog post about this topic here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/